# Azure ServiceBus SqlFilter Expression Syntax error

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

When adding a Rule to a SubscriptionClient, I get a syntax error if I don't remove all of the whitespace.  None of the numerous examples I've read have to do this.  Any ideas why?

```
// This works (whitespace stripped from expression)
var rd= new RuleDescription("ZonesRule", new SqlFilter("Zone='All'"));
subscriptionClient.AddRule(rd);

// This does not work (normal whitespace in expression)
var rd= new RuleDescription("ZonesRule", new SqlFilter("Zone = 'All'"));
subscriptionClient.AddRule(rd);
```

> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.FilterException: 'There was an error
>   parsing the SQL expression. [Token line=1, column=4, Token in error=
>    , **Additional details= Unrecognized character. ' '**] 
>   TrackingId:4087836f-321c-45d7-b217-cb7fae75ee67_G11_B27...'

Comment: The syntax has no problem at all. But as the error message indicates, there's an unrecognized whitespace character, is this code sample copied from somewhere? If so, the whitespace might be encoded which leads to a invalid character. You can try manually type the character to see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As forester123 mentioned that syntax has no problem at all. I also test it on my side, it works correctly.We also could get [SQLFilter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter) from azure official document.

[image]

If it is possible, please have a try use latest 4.1.3 version of [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/4.1.3/).

Comment: Yessir - After closer inspection there was a Unicode non-breaking space (%A0, or html &nbsp;) character in there instead of just a normal space.  Though I had already checked that.  Thanks guys!